# Help calculating a limit, if it's exists

Tags: calculus, limits

So i have this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{2(n+2)}+...+\sqrt{n(n+n)}}{n^2}$$

So i thought using a comparing method. So i know it's   $ \geq $ than  $\lim_{n\to \infty}0$
And i want to find if it's $\leq$ a limit $L=0$.
Or if this limit even exists. I presume it is $=0$,  because numerator is approximately $n$, denominator has $n^2$.
That's what i think at first sight, i could be wrong.

So any help woudl be appreciated.

Comment: The numerical value of the limit seems to be $0.840316\cdots\ $. I have no clue whether it has a closed form.

Comment: @Peter $\frac{1}{4} \left(3 \sqrt{2}-\sinh ^{-1}(1)\right)$ , simple integral computation

Comment: Simplicity is apparantly a matter of taste ...

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{2(n+2)}+...+\sqrt{n(n+n)}}{n^2} = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac kn \left(1+ \frac kn \right)}$$

The last sum should ring a bell.

Comment: it does ring a bell. But i cannot remember where exactly it is from

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife It's a Riemann sum.

Comment: oh yea i remember now

Answer (score 0):

If you take $dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, then the limit becomes $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n \sqrt{x(1+\frac{x}{n})} dx $, which leads to $\frac{3\sqrt{2}-\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{4}\approx 0.840316...$